# postfix evaluation using stack(problem with adding zeros for multidigit postfix expression)

Tags: c++, data-structures

the problem is that this code works perfectly except with numbers that inculde number (0) in them

the code was written in a way that it accepts multiple digits and because of this piece of code, 0 is pushed whenever a space is encountered.

```
else if (expression[i] == ' ') {
            push(digit);
            digit = 0;
            
        }
```

so i wrote this:

```
else if (expression[i] == ' ') {
            if (digit == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            push(digit);
            digit = 0;
            
        }
```

and it works perfectly! problem is when an expression has 0 in it such as
12 0 -
result would be = -12
when i check operands operand one is 0 and two is 12
which is supposed to be the opposite.
so what i've tried also to do was to include a counter(which i honestly don't know how it works but it works)
and the code now looks like this

```
else if (expression[i] == ' ') {
            if (digit == 0 && counter <= 1) {
                continue;
            }
            push(digit);
            digit = 0;
            counter--;
        }
```

counter is incremented when an operand is encountered, and is decremented when digit is pushed. Now the problem with this is that 12 0 - = 12 but 0 12 - = 0 although op1 = 0 and op2 = 12

any idea how i could go around fixing this?
how can i differentiate between zero because of finished multidigit number and actual zeros?

Comment: This seems more like a problem with your handling of the input and how you parse and tokenize the input. Please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).